# Using icons in UWP header template with xamarin.froms

Tags: xaml, uwp, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I am writing an application using Xamarin.Forms, and I want to show Icons in tabbed page for UWP app. To achieve this I'm trying to use custom renderer. Custom renderers code is

```
class TabbedPageWithIconsRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null && Control != null)
        {
            Control.HeaderTemplate = App.Current.Resources["TabHeaderTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
        }
    }
}
```

And data template style is:

```
<forms:ImageConverter x:Key="imageConverter" />

    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeaderTemplate">
        <StackPanel >
            <Image
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Margin="0,12,0,0"
                Height="24"
                Width="24"
                Source="{Binding Icon, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" />
            <TextBlock
                FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                Text="{Binding Title}"
                Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"
                LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"
                LineHeight="14"
                MaxLines="2"
                IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="False"
                TextAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Margin="2,5,2,7" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The problem is that Title works fine, but Icons never appear, however they are correctly assigned to each page in Forms.Xaml.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code and reproduced your issue. I resolved the issue by custom new image converter like following codes.

```cs
public class MyImageConverter:Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var temp = (value as FileImageSource).File;
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(temp));
        return source;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The return type of `Icon` is `Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource` when you set binding for `Source="{Binding Icon,Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}"`(although you have used the imageConverter,the expected effect was not achieved). And you used the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image` for your `TabHeaderTemplate`.
The `Image.Source` only accept `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource` type value.
So you could custom a converter just like code above.

Comment: Your converter sample worked. It seems that it is impossible to use standard Xamarin.Forms image converter for HeaderTemplate.